# How can I plot multiple vectors in Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: wolframalpha

If I have the following vectors:

- 55 degrees, 200 magnitude, start at origin
- 35 degrees, 130 magnitude, start at head of vector 1

How do I visualize them?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect there to be a more elegant way to express this, but while
this does not put the vectors "tip-to-tail" (sort of), it does compute and display the resulting vector:

vector (200*cos(55),200*sin(55))+(130*cos(35),130*sin(35))